# How can I source a CSH script with args in makefile target?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, csh

Is it possible to source a CSH script inside makefile given that I have majority of target commands in SH, and I don't want to change global shell of makefile to CSH?
In my makefile, I need to do something like this:

```
myTarget:     
    source specialPreCshellScript.csh
    some_SH_steps ...
    source specialPostCshellScript.csh
```

Thank you

Comment: What do the `csh` scripts do? Are they syntax compatible with `sh`?

Comment: "Sourcing" them makes no sense at all here. In your example, the shell which executes the first `source` will exit, losing any possible benefits of uring `source`. If the goal is to set some variables, perhaps at the end of the `csh` script, print out the values as variabne assignments in `sh` syntax, and source that from Make.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is simply to execute the commands in the `csh` script and not get any results back, there is no need to `source` it.

If you do need to get something back -- e.g. the values of some variables -- my proposal would be two write a `csh` wrapper script which prints those variables as `sh`-compatible assignments.

```
#!/bin/csh -f
source specialPreCshellScript.csh
printf "%s=%s\n" variable1 "$variable1" another "$another" third "$third"
```

Call it like

```
eval $(csh_wrapper_script); ... do stuff with the variables
```

Because of how Make works (by default) the settings you get from `eval` will be lost when the command line finishes. So in your example, `some_SH_steps` will not have access to the result from `csh` unless you force it to run in the same command line, perhaps like this:

```
eval $(csh_wrapper_script); some_SH_steps
```

and similarly tack on a wrapper for the second `csh` script after `some_SH_steps` if you need that to happen in the same context as well.

Comment: I could propose some suitable curse words for the author of the `csh` scripts but perhaps that would be more appropriate on https://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: The `printf` assumes that the variable values don't contain whitespace or shell metacharacters.  I'm imagining perhaps there would be a more elegant way to get the values out without repeating the variable name but I'm not planning on relearning `csh`.